# Where Case - why does this not return what its supposed to

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following fragment of a stored procedure:

```
@column1 varchar(50)
@column2 bit

SELECT column1 ,column2
FROM table1
WHERE column1 = case when @column1 = '' then column1 else @column1 end
  and column2 = case when @column2 = 0 then column2 else 1 end
```

does not return anything.

When I remove this line:

```
and column2 = case when @column2 = 0 then column2 else 1 end
```

it works as expected, as it should if `@column2 = 0`.

Is there a different/better way to do this?

Comment: is the bit field nullable

Comment: @vamsi Yes, Its nullable and there are null rows that appear when I take that line out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there were only null values in the database right now, all that was needed was ISNULL(column2, 0) = case when @column2 = 0 then column2 else 1 end

Answer (score 1):

A simpler, more readable and more reliable way is to only check the value if it *needs* checking:

```
WHERE (@column1 = '' OR column1 = @column1)
AND (@column2 = 0 OR column2 = @column2)
```

Or (probably) better, pass NULLs for your variables when you don't require a particular value:

```
WHERE (@column1 IS NULL OR column1 = @column1)
AND (@column2 IS NULL OR column2 = @column2)
```

Using NULLs also allows `column1` to require a blank and `column2` to require a `0`, values which is not possible when you reserve those values to mean "don't care" (this issue applies to whatever approach you eventually use)

Answer (score 0):

Use (NULL OR Value) AND (NULL OR Value)

```
@column1 varchar(50)
@column2 bit

SELECT column1
      ,column2
FROM table1
WHERE 
  ((@column1 IS NULL OR @Column1='') OR column1 = @column1)
  and 
  ((@column2 IS NULL) OR column2 = @column2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You run into problems with `NULL` since `NULL=NULL` is not true.

Use conditions like this instead, which are also easier on the query optimizer:

```
WHERE ((@column1 = '') OR (column1 = @column1))
```

**Hint:** If you have this in a stored procedure, it may be a good idea to add an `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` at the end of the statement in order to have the query optimizer re-run while taking the `@` variables into account as constants.